# Load .csv database on R but don't read emojis

Tags: r, emoji, iconv

I try to load this database

[emoji csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqool.png)

I import it to rstudio via the import database option, but then when I go to analyze the "message" column I notice that the emoji does not read them to me, I see them with this writing for example: ðŸ ’™.

[image]

I tried in various ways, both with iconv, and to reload database but I can't find any solution, what should I do?

Comment: try different encodings

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the locale explicitly e.g. using `locale(encoding = "UTF-8")`:

Content of example data file `data.csv`:

```
name,value
smile,
```

Code:

```r
library(readr)
read_csv("data.csv", locale = locale(encoding = "UTF-8"))
#> 
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> cols(
#>   name = col_character(),
#>   value = col_character()
#> )
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   name  value
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 smile 
read_csv("data.csv", locale = locale(encoding = "latin1"))
#> 
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> cols(
#>   name = col_character(),
#>   value = col_character()
#> )
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   name  value                
#>   <chr> <chr>                
#> 1 smile "ð\u009f\u0098\u008a"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I have noticed but mimic this error     Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  unused argument (locale = list(list(c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"), c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"), c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"), c("AM", "PM")), "%AD", "%AT", ".", ",", "UTC", "UTF-8"))

Comment: I used `read_csv` instead of `read.table`

Comment: I also use read.csv, I don't know why in the error it tells me that I use read.table

Comment: > posts <- read.csv("posts.csv", locale = locale(encoding = "UTF-8"))
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  unused argument (locale = list(list(c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"), c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"), c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"), c("AM", "PM")), "%AD", "%AT", ".", ",", "UTC", "UTF-8"))

Comment: In `read.table` the argument name is `encoding`, not `locale`. And `read.csv` is `read.table` with some arguments set.

Comment: as not mentioned, the problem is that I used read.csv, now I used read_csv and I solved it, thank you very much very kind

Comment: `read_csv` is also different from `read.csv`